# $dir =~ s/__math_eqn__/$fun->{'VAR'}{'math_eqn'}/g; do in perl

Tags: perl

What does this command do? , I know this is for replacing but since I am unaware of the operator I am getting confused.

`$dir =~ s/__math_eqn__/$fun->{'VAR'}{'math_eqn'}/g;`

Comment: Which operator?

Comment: it is doing a [global substitution](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) on the string `$dir`. The substring `__math_eqn__` is replaced by the hash value `$fun->{VAR}{math_eqn}`  (where `$fun` is a hash reference)

Comment: @simbabque '__' and ->{}{} , these operators.

Comment: @HåkonHægland what does $fun->{}{} do with 'VAR' and 'math_eqn'

Comment: @shanujgarg It just looks up a hash value in the nested hash `%$fun`, see [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) and [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is doing a [global substitution](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) on the string `$dir`. 
The substring `__math_eqn__` is replaced by the hash value `$fun->{VAR}{math_eqn}` (where `$fun` is a hash reference), for example:

```
my $fun = {
    VAR => { math_eqn => "2 + 2 = 4" }
};
my $dir = "This is the example equation: __math_eqn__,  and "
  . " here is the equation once more: __math_eqn__";
$dir =~ s/__math_eqn__/$fun->{'VAR'}{'math_eqn'}/g;
say $dir;
```

**Output**:

```
This is the example equation: 2 + 2 = 4,  and  here is the equation once more: 2 + 2 = 4
```

See [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) and [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information.